# Enhance current SQLite query

Tags: sqlite

I inherited an old SQLite database I should not change (this is a requirement). There are many tables, but I will focus on two of them:

```
songs
----------
song_id (primary autoincrement)
group_id (external)
title
audio_file_path
wasPurchased (boolean, 0/1)

groups
----------
group_id (primary autoincrement, related to songs group_id)
group_name
```

At the moment, the application needs to perform this query:

```
SELECT song_id,title,audio_file_path,wasPurchased,G.group_name AS groupName,
G.group_id AS groupId FROM songs AS S JOIN groups AS G ON S.group_id=G.group_id 
ORDER BY groupName DESC
```

Is there any way, with the same query, to extract how many distinct G.group_id have wasPurchased=0?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT song_id,title,audio_file_path,wasPurchased,
G.group_name AS groupName, G.group_id AS groupId,
 SUM (SELECT DISTINCT g.group_id 
      FROM yourtables/JOIN 
      WHERE wasPurchased = 0) as nb 
FROM songs AS S 
JOIN groups AS G ON S.group_id=G.group_id 
ORDER BY groupName DESC
```

Not sure if it's the best way(never tried a select in a sum but...), but I think it will help you.

Comment: I found a different solution, with a subquery (like yours) and without JOIN and SUM: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(group_id)) FROM songs WHERE purchased = 0) AS nb`. Your solution does a slightly different thing, so maybe I explained bad my needs.